# how can we use preg_match_all()in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there any RoR method which can work same as preg_match_all() php function?

Answer (score 0):

Use scan :

```
string = 'joe@example.com; walter@example.org'
result = string.scan(/([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([a-z0-9-]+)\.[a-z.]+/i)
p result.size
# => 2

p result
# => [["joe", "example"], ["walter", "example"]]
```

there is a good article here: http://railsforphp.com/2008/01/17/regular-expressions-in-ruby/

Comment: i want output as ['joe@example.com','walter@example.org']